# imacros firefox loop through results and extract

Tags: javascript, loops, firefox-addon, screen-scraping, imacros

I am using the imacros free plugin for firefox to scrape data from a javascript search form on a website.  Here is a breakdown of my current macro which works to extract one set of results for me.

The portion of the macro below automatically enters the keyword "superman" into the search form.

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.example.com/pricelist
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/Pricelistsearchform/ ATTR=ID:Keyphrase CONTENT=superman
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:/Pricelistsearchform ATTR=NAME:SearchBarcode&&VALUE:Get<SP>Value
```

A list of results will then load.  I now use the following xpath expression to select the first result that appears in the list:

```
TAG XPATH=id('SearchForm')/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a
```

The form now reloads with the name and price of the selected product and i use these two XPATH expressions to extract this data:

```
TAG XPATH=id('Results')/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2] EXTRACT=TXT
TAG XPATH=id('Results')/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4] EXTRACT=TXT
BACK
```

I then use the BACK statement which brings me back to my results list.

This all works fine to extract the first result in the list i.e "superman".  However there are many other results which i would like to loop through and scrape (superman 2, superman 3, superman special edition e.t.c).  The multiple results are listed in the following format:

```
TAG XPATH=id('SearchForm')/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a   ..i.e superman
TAG XPATH=id('SearchForm')/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a   ..i.e superman 2
TAG XPATH=id('SearchForm')/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/a   ..i.e superman 3 ...etc
```

I would like to use a loop to select each of these results one at a time, extract their name and price and then go back and select the next result in the list and so on.
I assume i need to use the wildcard (*) symbol and the {{!LOOP}} statement but im unsure of how to implement these in my code or whether i need to use Javascript.

Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
set !loop 3
TAG XPATH=id('SearchForm')/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[{{!loop}}]/td[1]/a
```

or simple

```
set !loop 3
tag pos={{!loop}} type=a attr=id:SearchForm extract=txt
```